# Migrate from next.js 12

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, next.js

hope everyone is well!
So basically I was given a task to migrate a project from next.js version 12 to the newest version, and because of the difference from the pages routing to the app routing I'm having a bit of trouble to know how to migrate the entire website.
Is there like an "easier" way to do it? or you can only go file by file to do it?
Thanks a lot

I´m kind of a noob still in next.js so I'm just trying to understand how to handle this situation.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading

Answer (score 1):

The `app` directory is intentionally designed to work simultaneously with the `pages` directory to allow a step-by-step migration from page to page. The easiest way is probably to mirror it file by file. For more information:

https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration